# Display Contact,Logs and Favourite Contact in Listview in Single Activity

Tags: android, android-contacts

I want to create the Contact Activity which contains Three tabs

1) Contact Address
2) Contact Logs   (Recently used)
3) favourite Contact ( Often Used)

Please tell me how to achieve this tabs should contain listview to display all the contact

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am planning to create the fragment and fetch the contact list and display in the listview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For tutorial on creating tabs using fragment, [this](http://www.lucazanini.eu/2012/android/tab-layout-in-android-with-actionbar-and-fragment/?lang=en) website can help.

For your `ListView`, you can use [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listfragments). The thing to take note of is that you need your class to extend `ListFragment` instead of `Fragment`.

Hope this helps =)

Comment: Thanks i am done with fragment next i am trying to retrieve the contact in tab to display in list , but how to access this "getContentResolver" in ListFragment ? I cant access Context over here , please tell me i am learning

Comment: I'm also still learning, and am not really good at it yet. I will try my best. Usually, from inside `Fragment`, `ListFragment`etc, you use `getActivity()` to replace `this` that you use `Activity`. Or maybe `getActivity().getApplicationContext()`. Hope that is what you wanted.